# Enabling in page uploads

Tags: mediawiki

From what I understand the default method of uploading to MediaWiki is using the upload page.

However, on MediaWiki's own site and WikiPedia you are able to upload images via the page editor (Visual Editor or Enhanced Wiki Editor). Seems like I don't have the upload tab that MediaWiki has. Is this custom functionality or something I can enable?

Comment: Are you meaning that you want the same functionality but standalone, or that uploads on your wiki are disabled (Special:Uploads doesn't work)?

Comment: Uploads via Special:Uploads works fine. However, WikiMedia is able to upload images in the page you're editing real time. Added screen grabs for clarification

[upload-button](http://i.imgur.com/2QdINg9.png)
[mine](http://i.imgur.com/SUsXJ61.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. This feature is called "cross-wiki upload" and is available in the 1.27 Alpha release. I was using 1.26 which is the latest stable release at this time.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Cross-wiki_upload

Comment: Actually this is not [UploadWizard](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadWizard) (which has been available for quite a while) but a core feature called [cross-wiki uploads](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Cross-wiki_upload), and it was [backported](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/rMW03e6ac38bf51456d9035b58040422358c41939f7) to 1.26.